# Firebase Analytics dotted lines

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

have integrated Firebase Analytics into my Android project, it was working last month, now it shows only dotted lines and users count is 0.

Not sure why it's happening, where am I wrong? Since it was working previously, I believe that I had setup everything correct as per development guide.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now. I double checked gradle file, the below line was commented out accidentally and thats what the reason for non-tracking in my case.

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

I wonder how I get successful message while initializing the analytics and I dont receive any build issue. So strange.

Answer (score 4):

Those dotted lines are the graphs for the previous 30 days (it's useful when you're wondering how the current time period compares to that of the previous time period).

Basically, it looks like about 35 days ago, you started adding Firebase Analytics to you app. Everything seemed to be going well until about 5-10 days later, when your usage dropped off to nothing.

Unfortunately, I can't really tell from a graph why things stopped working. My guess might be you accidentally shipped an updated version of your app with Analytics turned off, or used an incorrect config file. I would double-check the latest version of your app and confirm that you're not seeing anything unusual in the logs that might indicate some sort of error.